# Woher kommt die Redensart: Aus der Reserve locken?

Tags: etymology, phrase

Nach eigener Recherche habe ich das [Folgende](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=%7E%7Ejemanden%20aus%20der%20Reserve%20locken&bool=relevanz&sp0=rart_ou) gefunden:

> Ein zurückhaltendes, vorsichtiges Verhalten wurde früher ebenfalls als "Reserve" bezeichnet (z. B. eine Nachricht mit aller Reserve mitteilen, heute spricht man eher von Reserviertheit). Hier liegt wohl der Ursprung der Redensart.

Ich finde, diese Bedeutung ist naheliegend, aber sie überzeugt mich nicht vollständig. Wenn ich das Wort "Reserve" höre bzw. lese, dann denke ich an zwei Dinge:

- Eine Reserve an Nahrungsmitteln oder anderen Dingen.
- Eine Reserve im militärischen Sinne, z. B. eine Kompanie.

Weiß denn hier jemand mehr über diese Redensart oder liegt der Ursprung wirklich da, wo es das obige Zitat vemutet?

Comment: Hm, was ist mit der Etymologie vom Wort "Reserve"? Was ist da so niedergeschrieben? Denn ich denke, das Wort muss zur Zeit der Redensart eine "irgendwie verwandte" Bedeutung gehabt haben. (https://www.dwds.de/wb/Reserve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wo eine Redewendung ursprünglich herstammt ist oft schwer zu sagen. Dass das hier verwendete Wort Reserve, in der von redensarten-index vorgeschlagenen Bedeutung, von französischen Wort réservé abstammt legt [DWDS ebenfalls nahe](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Reserve).

> Dazu reserviert Part.adj. ‘zurückhaltend, kühl, abweisend, verschlossen’ (2. Hälfte 19. Jh., nach mfrz. frz. réservé ‘zurückhaltend, bedächtig’), ‘vorbestellt, freigehalten’ (um 1900) und Reserviertheit f. ‘kühles, zurückhaltendes Benehmen’ (2. Hälfte 19. Jh.).

Folgende [Webseite](http://fechtfabrik.de/deutsche-sprache-fechtsprache-begriffe-und-redensarten/) gibt an, dass das Sprichwort aus der Fechtsprache kommt. Allerdings ohne weitere Quellen anzuführen.

> „Aus der Reserve locken“ -
> Die Reserve ist der französische Ausdruck für „Vorbehalt“, welcher wiederum das Verhalten eines Fechters bezeichnet, der das „Vor“ für sich behalten will.  Ein solcher Fechter hält sich zurück und lauert auf die Bewegung des Gegners. Sobald dieser sich bewegt, legt dieser seinen Vorbehalt ein und kontert ihn. Einen solchen Fechter sollte man aus der Reserve locken.

Bedenkt man, dass die Fechtbegriffe aus dem [Französischen](http://www.fechten.org/der-verband/historie/) stammen liegt die Vermutung nahe, dass auch die Redewendung tatsächlich ihren Ursprung dort hat. Mit allerletzter Bestimmtheit lässt sich das aber auf die Art nicht belegen, auch weil Reserve kein bekannter [Fechtbegriff](http://www.fechten.org/fechten/handzeichen-kampfrichter/) wie "En garde" oder "Touché" ist.

Comment: Das überzeugt mich schon deutlich eher, danke! Ich finde, man kann sich quasi vor Augen führen, dass "jemanden aus der Reserve locken" seinen Ursprung hat im Fechten, wo man sein Gegenüber zu unüberlegten Aktionen drängen möchte.